# CK Editor to support math formulas in rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I am using CK editor in my project and now i want to apply extra plugin for adding mathematical formula in CK editor.

I tried out CK editor math formula documentation but not clear at all how to do.
http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/mathjax.html

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_mathjax

My config.js file is look like this

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 config.extraPlugins = 'mathjax';
 config.mathJaxClass = 'equation';
 config.mathJaxLib   = 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';
}
```

This code is not work.

i miss-out something or i am doing it in  wrong way ?

please help me out.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i got the solution.

I replaced current gem

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

to

https://github.com/matismasters/ckeditor_mathml

now it's work perfectly.

Comment: EDITCould you suggest what exactly should I do? I can't figure out how to show the equations in show page after saving it. All it show it is: `<span class="equation">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>`. When I am writing the equation in window it shows fine.

Comment: can anyone please answer this?